# Implementation of removeNode for a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a removal algorithm discussed in a textbook for a binary search tree in a program, but the book is scant on details for some of the functions described so I've guessed at their meaning and implemented the functions it specified and some of my own. The problem I'm having is with the `removeNode` function on handling the 0-1-2 children cases.

In the book it specifies the following pseudocode for `removeNode`

```
removeNode(N: BinaryNode)
{
if(N is a leaf)
    Remove N from the tree
else if (N has only one child C)
{
    if(N was a left child of its parent P)
        Make C the left child of P
    else
        Make C the right child of P
}
else //Node has two children
{
    //Find S, the node that contains N's inorder successor
    //Copy the item from node S into node N
    //Remove S from the tree by using the previous
    //technique for a leaf or a node with one child
}
```

In this function, **how do you make C a child of P**? given a single node with nothing to point back to the parent what can you do to figure out who the parent of the tree is? Usually you need a trailing node to keep track of that but due to the books 'final draft' I suspect that wasn't what they were implying.

'Final Draft'

```
removeNode(nodePtr: BinaryNodePointer): BinaryNodePointer
{
 if(N is a leaf)
 {
    //Remove leaf from the tree
    delete nodePtr
    nodePtr = nullPtr
    return nodePtr
 }
    else if (N has only one child C)
    {
        if(N was a left child of its parent P)
            nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->getleftChildPtr() //<---I assume this means nodePtr->left
        else
            nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->getRightChildPtr() //<--nodePtr->right?
        delete nodePtr
        nodePtr = nullptr
        return nodeToConnectPtr
    }
    else //Node has two children
    {
        //Find the inorder succesor of the entry in N: it is in the left subtree rooted
        //at N's Child
        tempPtr = removeLeftMosstNode(nodePtr->getRightChild(), newNodeValue)
        nodePtr->setRightChildPtr(tempPtr) //<--nodePtr->right = tempPtr?
        nodePtr->setItem(newNodeValue) // nodePtr->vendorData = newNodeValue?
        return nodePtr
    }
```

This is the implementation I came up with based off the aforementioned design. I know some parts are wrong but I wasn't sure what else I could do to fix them. Could anyone suggest a fix the child cases and any other problems I might have missed?

My Implementation

```
aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeNode(aBst::treeNode * nodePtr)
    {
        //This functions deletes a node and then returns the pointer to the child to take the place of deleted child
        aVendor * tempVendorPtr;
        treeNode * nodeToConnectPtr, *tempPtr;

        //The node passed is the node that needs to be removed
        if (nodePtr->right == NULL && nodePtr->left == NULL) //----No Child----
        {
            delete nodePtr;
            nodePtr = NULL;
            return nodePtr;
        }
        else if ((nodePtr->right != NULL) != (nodePtr->left != NULL))//----One Child----
        {
            if (nodePtr->left != NULL)//left child
            {
                nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->left; //Wrong
            }
            else if (nodePtr->right != NULL) //right child
            {
                nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->right; //Wrong
            }

            delete nodePtr;
            nodePtr = NULL;
            return nodeToConnectPtr;
        }
        else //-----Two Child-----
        {
            //find minimum value of right subtree, stores the pointer to the vendorData it carries through the parameter and calls removeNode
            tempPtr = removeLeftMostNode(nodePtr->right, tempVendorPtr);
            nodePtr->vendorData = tempVendorPtr;
            nodePtr->right = tempPtr;
            return nodePtr;
        }

    }
```

All functions

```
int aBst::countKids(aBst::treeNode * subTreePtr)
{
    if (subTreePtr == NULL) //Empty Tree
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (subTreePtr->right == NULL && subTreePtr->left == NULL) //----No Child----
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((subTreePtr->right != NULL) != (subTreePtr->left != NULL))//----One Child----
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((subTreePtr->right != NULL) && (subTreePtr->left != NULL))//----Two Child----
    {
        return 2;
    }
    //Something unexpected occurred         
    return -1;
}

bool aBst::remove(char nameOfVendor[])
{
    bool failControl = false;

    removeValue(root, nameOfVendor, failControl);

    return failControl;
}

aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeValue(aBst::treeNode * subTreePtr, char nameOfVendor[], bool& success)
{
    //Note: the subTreePtr should be root in initial call
    treeNode * tmpPtr;
    char name[MAX_CHAR_LENGTH];

    //Make sure passed success bit is false
    success = false;

    subTreePtr->vendorData->getName(name);

    if (subTreePtr == NULL) //Empty Tree
    {
        success = false;
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (strcmp(name, nameOfVendor) == 0) //Evaluates to true if there is a match
    {
        subTreePtr = removeNode(subTreePtr);
        success = true;
        return subTreePtr;
    }
    else if (strcmp(name, nameOfVendor) > 0) // Go left
    {
        //Protects algorithm from bad data crash
        if (subTreePtr->left == NULL)
        {
            return subTreePtr;
        }

        tmpPtr = removeValue(subTreePtr->left, nameOfVendor, success);
        subTreePtr->left = tmpPtr;
        return subTreePtr;
    }
    else // Go Right
    {   
        //Protects algorithm from bad data crash
        if (subTreePtr->right == NULL)
        {
            return subTreePtr;
        }

        tmpPtr = removeValue(subTreePtr->right, nameOfVendor, success);
        subTreePtr->right = tmpPtr;
        return subTreePtr;
    }

    //For loop was broken and function returns false
    return subTreePtr;
}



aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeNode(aBst::treeNode * nodePtr)
{
    aVendor * tempVendorPtr;
    treeNode * nodeToConnectPtr, *tempPtr;

    //The node passed is the node that needs to be removed
    if (nodePtr->right == NULL && nodePtr->left == NULL) //----No Child----
    {
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = NULL;
        return nodePtr;
    }
    else if ((nodePtr->right != NULL) != (nodePtr->left != NULL))//----One Child----
    {
        if (nodePtr->left != NULL)//left child
        {
            nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->left;
        }
        else if (nodePtr->right != NULL) //right child
        {
            nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->right;
        }

        delete nodePtr;
        cout << "called\n";
        nodePtr = NULL;
        return nodeToConnectPtr;
    }
    else //-----Two Child-----
    {
        //find minimum value of right subtree, stores the pointer to the vendorData it carries through the parameter and calls removeNode
        tempPtr = removeLeftMostNode(nodePtr->right, tempVendorPtr);
        nodePtr->vendorData = tempVendorPtr;
        nodePtr->right = tempPtr;
        cout << "\nleaving Two Child\n";
        return nodePtr;
    }

}

aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeLeftMostNode(aBst::treeNode * nodePtr, aVendor*& vendorDataRef)
{
    if (nodePtr->left == NULL)
    {
        //Target acquired
        vendorDataRef = nodePtr->vendorData;
        return removeNode(nodePtr);
    }
    else
        return removeLeftMostNode(nodePtr->left, vendorDataRef);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a similar problem as I do. What you're doing when there is only one child, is just setting the pointer to branch to the right or left respectively. But you need to replace the node with a node from that subtree. This can be done by searching for the minimum node in the left subtree and replacing the node you wanted to remove with this minimum node. Then you need to remove the node you just inserted to prevent node duplication. That's the theory anyway. I haven't managed to implement it correctly myself.

edit: I removed the link again. I saw that it is considered bad etiquette to ask something in an answer. Shame on me /o.

Comment: The problem only seems to exist when root is modified in runtime, so I suspect that I may need to test for root and update it on each case.